# Create background within another background

Tags: android

I wanted to create the following:

I am using a Relative Layout & assigning a background colour "Blue" . 
I wanted to draw another background color(black) with space from margins. Also , I wanted to have rounded edges of the black rectangle(not on the picture)

Kindly provide the sample code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide this code=

```
public class DrawDemo extends Activity {
    DemoView demoview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        demoview = new DemoView(this);
        setContentView(demoview);
    }
    private class DemoView extends View{
        public DemoView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawRect(16, 16, getWidth()-16, getHeight()-16, paint);

        }
    }
}
```

Best, :)

Comment: you should edit your original question instead of providing a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the code papachan .. wanted to know if it is possible to create the same code with layout xml or rather include the sample code on a class & include on the layout file?

Comment: OK,willytate, i will delete my last response.

Comment: yes sure, Chiranjib, just use a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout with setting color with android:Background !